FAILURE: Build failed with an exception. Error resolving plugin [id: 'com.facebook.react.settings']
this error occurs when I running the newly created plain react native app:
npx @react-native-community/cli@latest init <Project Name>

after I ensure with
npx react-native doctor

to ensure all the requirements has been fullfilled (this requirement is fullfilled for mine)
Lastly, I trying to run using
npx react-native run-android

this will through the error of
id: com.facebook.react.settings

I tried to deleting the folder of android\.gradle and again run the server with cache clean
npm start --reset-cache 

again the same error comes
Does anyone having any solutions or suggestions?

Please try with bellow way.

Delete your node_module folder and try with npm install and npx react-native run-android.


I even tried for that also but not the issue still not fixed

Please rollback the version to 0.75.4 or make new project with npx react-native init projectname --version 0.75.4

I fixed that issue com.facebook.react.settings and Task :app:configureCMakeDebug[arm64-v8a] FAILED #37124
run the following command after creating the React-Native project :
npx react-native doctor

to make sure all the requirements should be satisfied

start the metro server using the command:

from here i got the com.facebook.react.settings error to fix:

Inside your project delete the .gradle file under the android folder
Clearing the cache before starting the server

using
npm start --reset-cache

or
yarn start --reset-cache

check if the build folder is generated under the android folder

To fix Cmake Error - task ':app:configureCMakeDebug[arm64-v8a]':

inside the gradle.properties file to change the value of

newArchEnabled=true to newArchEnabled=false

Finally, run
npx react-native run-android


